# Typescript can't find property even though declared

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to modify a type declaration for a package that I'm using since the types are outdated. I'm able to adjust most things fine, but there is one error I don't seem to be able to fix, and that is that a property of an interface that is returned from the function.

Here is a code sample. I have stripped out code I am pretty sure are not related to the issue, to make reading it easier. If you feel there is something missing that might help understand the problem, please let me know.

```js
declare namespace renderContent {
  type renderContentCallback = (
    eventOrImage: Event | HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLImageElement,
    data?: MetaData
  ) => void;

  interface ImageHead {
    imageHead?: ArrayBuffer | Uint8Array;
  }

  interface MetaData extends ImageHead {
    //...
  }

  interface PromiseData extends MetaData {
    image: HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLImageElement;
  }

  interface BasicOptions {
    //...
  }

  type renderContentOptions = BasicOptions
}

interface renderContent {
  (
    file: File | Blob | string,
    /* If options are defined instead of a callback function, the next argument will be skipped and the function will return a promise */
    callbackOrOption?: renderContent.renderContentCallback | renderContent.renderContentOptions,
    options?: renderContent.renderContentOptions
  ): HTMLImageElement | FileReader | Promise<renderContent.PromiseData> | false;
}

declare const renderContent: renderContent;

export = renderContent;
```

When I then use this in my code like so:

```js
const { image } = await renderContent(file, options);
```

I get an error saying:

> Property 'image' does not exist on type 'false | HTMLImageElement |
>   FileReader | PromiseData'

To me, it seems it is clearly defined in the *PromiseData* interface, listed in the error message. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, typescript cannot know for sure that the type returned by `renderContent` will be `Promise<renderContent.PromiseData>`. In fact, for typescript the type could also be `FileReader` or `HtMLImageElement`...

Theses types doesn't have the key `image`, and this is why you got this error.

I suppose that you think that using the keyword `await` would make typescript guess that `Promise<renderContent.PromiseData>` is the correct returned type, but unfortunately no.

---

In order to tell typescript what you are waiting for, use the keyword `as`, like :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=39&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMC6NBgGEB7RAFxAvgG8AoeecgT0zysNIqvKKgggAjHAGt4AXngAKBo3ggAbjwDyMAJIooAcxAAueAFEl1AD7wAEgBUAsgBk+iBVHQGIINKYs3bG7SFfuPAA0sozAUORQAPz61iCRACIRULIAlBIAfPAKJACWwADcdLK53DAAZjgIvjrmIFDAtKHwuZq19cAx8ACCMDBQzABCAK7l5SAw8GYAqqXkABy9-cxFjAC+xYxzE5W48HGJyfIAHpQE6PA1IHUNTXLwAPQP8AB0b7IbJWW7CAAKMCQULl0CAkpETmdgBcDlAwVA7nJWn59FY7A4nC43B5yFMvHYrgFsat4J8tt8qvBBs5cmBlJhyLkyBd6Pcnq93utNkxWOwCBMuGdyHSGUyJJTqbT6YzEOg6J9thUKfhOGRBQiZPdyrk3PoAGLahBmQYQEiCXHocgwUpaEKsgBUl3K8BIUtFsAQoC1iBAjVKFo6zqd8LA-CEong5WGiDAIsQQSYAAsEN7TvBYFphtj4AB3bUQeCCBDoES5TBsRpQAiJhCR6OxnN5+BwcjDGCINPwTAAoEg+B2h7NEMCYRgESqYXSrrK-mqngvafEWcUPjD8NmBcCucbpdC10y21yF2x9BTjgz7gUednxcX3fHtIo7wErE8XH6twAJQ6E1x-0BwJAAAebdbxeP8e1BZIsjMSoIBBIpPlASB3XgMAmRxEDBX0TCeCKOgpGcZhoykdJxCyFk5DQmUcRoFo2gQNYxSgbMoFyHEpBwigpFg3tnHgKMREQEhs3bPj3xAdI+PAgDgOvTdL2kkE4QyVIENSEiCiAA)

```
const { image } = await (renderContent(_) as Promise<renderContent.PromiseData>);
```

---

#### About the **&** solution :

It may work, but with side effects. As example :

If you use the function like :

```
 const data = renderContent(false as unknown as File);
```

Typescript will allow you to call `data.readAsArrayBuffer` as much as `data.height`, which is wrong. Because `renderContent` returns either a `HTMLCanvasElement`, either a `HTMLImageElement`.

---

#### A new solution! With a bit of rework :

All considered, a better solution would be to exactly describe what the `renderContent` call scenarios looks like :

```
type possibilityA = (
    file: File | Blob | string,
    options: renderContent.renderContentOptions
) => Promise<renderContent.PromiseData>;

type possibilityB = (
    file: File | Blob | string,
    callback: renderContent.renderContentCallback,
) => HTMLImageElement | FileReader | false;

type possibilityC = (
    file: File | Blob | string,
    callback: renderContent.renderContentCallback,
    options: renderContent.renderContentOptions
) => HTMLImageElement | FileReader | false;

type renderContent = possibilityA & possibilityB & possibilityC;

declare const renderContent: renderContent;

(async() => {
  const data = await renderContent('foo', {  });
})();
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=48&ssc=6&pln=26&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMC6NBgGEB7RAFxAvgG8AoeecgT0zysNIqvKKgggAjHAGt4AXngAKBo3ggAbjwDyMAJIooAcxAAueAFEl1AD7wAEgBUAsgBk+iBVHQGIINKYs3bG7SFfuPAA0sozAUORQAPz61iCRACIRULIAlBIAfPAKJACWwADcdLK53DAAZjgIvjrmIFDAtKHwuZq19cAx8ACCMDBQzABCAK7l5SAw8GYAqqXkABy9-cxFjAC+xYxzE5W48HGJyfIAHpQE6PA1IHUNTXLwAPQP8AB0b7IbJWW7CAAKMCQULl0CAkpETmdgBcDlAwVA7nJWn59FY7A4nC43B5yFMvHYrgFsat4J8tt8qvBBs5cmBlJhyLkyBd6Pcnq93utNkxWOwCBMuGdyHSGUyJJTqbT6YzEOg6J8WGx4JgSOh0LlBLkILkWN0xTJ7uVNXp4AAxI24wYQEiCXHocgwUpaEL3EhSpn6fCcMiCl6e-nelRumV0dLiLL-QHAkAAHj9xADFBeEaBILhGSKdAVCGVqvVmu1Qz1zUNbn0ZrcFqtNrMdodiCdzTA-CEog9HH93ETcYFPD4AmEYBEIVDWVRPja-ixPFx5ZAACUOhNcZUICCM1mlSq1RqtSwiEWDUay+azJbrbb7Y7nXIm-3W-BuwnyL72-HO7xmwOh81XSKZW2+TfH1H3fYVpVlEc8XHPxCWnMxZwXBolzMFc12KDcQMFMUc23fMdXgAAyTdcx3AtBkI4jcN3ZgiAzUBIFgBAwCZHFMJ4ACvXfDMpGcZhEDAKRIJZeBmJlHFwnBSQoAAdygbUH1fHsKCkABycoSBIFSglodZUiKNZUkEgogA)

In this soluce, typescript will pick the appropriate overload depending on the parameter you provide which will define the type of `data` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Grégory, this seems to work, I was able to get this to work with `const { image } = await (renderContent(file as File, option) as Promise<renderContent.PromiseData>);`

But I also just discovered that I could fix the problem, without modifying the function, by changing the expected return to `HTMLImageElement & FileReader & Promise<renderContent.PromiseData> & false`. Might there be a reason that is not a recommended approach?

Comment: @EinarÓlafsson I've edited my post with an answer to you and another soluce that is handling all the cases! _(good autocompletion and typechecking)_

Comment: That solution work very well, thank you very much for the explanation of the implementation, it is very very helpful!